# How to change the text color of a menu item in Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar theme?

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat, android-menu

I have black background with white letters.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

```
        <style name="PacerTheme"            
                parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">                                
            <item name="android:itemBackground">@android:color/black</item>
            <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/myCustomMenuTextApearance</item>                                           
        </style>

        <style name="myCustomMenuTextApearance" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
            <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>             
        </style>
```

Normal:

[image: Normal]

Click in menu button, and show :

[image: Menu]

Answer (score 1):

Modify the style like this:

```
<style name="PacerTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/myCustomMenuTextApearance</item>                                           
</style>

<style name="myCustomMenuTextApearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

For "myCustomMenuTextApearance" style use for parent

```
@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item
```

instead of

```
@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, program change text color, as follows:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
  {
    for(int i=0; i<menu.size(); i++) 
    {
        MenuItem mi = menu.getItem(i);
        String title = mi.getTitle().toString();
        Spannable newTitle = new SpannableString(title);        
        newTitle.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, newTitle.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        mi.setTitle(newTitle);
    }
    return true;
  }
```

The XML is as follows:

```
 <style name="PacerTheme"            
        parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">                                
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@android:color/black</item>                                         
 </style>
```